# Syntax highlighting of single line comments ending with backslash broken

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

**C**:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Path to typical Windows directory: ");
    // We need to escape backslashes: \
    printf("C:\\Windows\\\n");
    printf("Can you see it?\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**C++**:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Path to typical Windows directory: ";
    // We need to escape backslashes: \
    std::cout << "C:\\Windows\\" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Can you see it?" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The syntax highlighting of single line comments of C/C++ ending with a backslash (`\`) is broken.

Comments ending with a backslash should continue to the following line, but as you can see it is incorrectly highlighted.

The problem is discovered from an answer to a question on [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). Link: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11446

Comment: You can add some codepad/ideone links like [this](http://codepad.org/Okwd1HyK) for C-example and [this](http://ideone.com/7OedYy) for the C++ one. :)

Comment: Highlighting bugs like this should be reported to [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

Comment: I know this problem when writing (and discarding) an answer to remove comments in C/C++ with regex. I guess the current code assumes that ``//`` works only on a single line, while "forgetting" that it actually can be extended...

Comment: @hammar I guess it is up to the devs at SE to handle this. They may decide to change it, hack it or report the bug to Prettify. Who knows?

Comment: @AlvinWong: Based on previous answers, I'd say that SE probably won't bother with a small issue like this one. But they are usually happy to pull in a new version of Prettify when it has been fixed there. Prettify is open source, so you can even contribute a fix yourself if you are able to.